# COM components are getting error?

Tags: asp.net

in my application i am trying to get my outlook contacts it is working fine in my system (local) but when i uploaded the code into our server which is some where. I am getting the error like this

Retrieving the COM Class factory for component with CLSID failed due to the following error:80040154

i added the outlook  reference in server also. still it is getting the error.
can u help me

Comment: possible duplicate of [Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {XXXX} failed due to the following error: 80040154.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1036856/retrieving-the-com-class-factory-for-component-with-clsid-xxxx-failed-due-to-th)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a 64bit issue like [Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {XXXX} failed due to the following error: 80040154](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1036856/retrieving-the-com-class-factory-for-component-with-clsid-xxxx-failed-due-to-th/1037013#1037013).

Is the server running a 64bit edition of Windows?

The following link may be of interest to you [Using X86 COM interop with ASP.Net application in Windows x64](http://blogs.msdn.com/helloworld/archive/2007/07/14/using-x86-com-interop-with-asp-net-application-in-windows-x64.aspx).

Comment: Thank you for response Mr. Stevo3000. i will let you know

Comment: what is this 64bit and 34bit can i know more details or is there any reference to study in detail

Comment: @Surya sasidhar - Right click on the My Computer icon and select properties. The windows edition will tell you if it's 64bit.

Answer (score 0):

The asp.net worker process may not have sufficient permissions to do the COM calls. I'm not sure what the exact permissions will be but it definately needs registery permissions and permissions on the outlook executeable

Comment: Mr. rip how can i solve this problem and thank you for response

Comment: First find out what user account the ASP.NET worker process is running under. Note: System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name should give you this. Then elevate the permissions for this account on the relevant resources. For example to give registry permissions, open regedit, go to Edit > Permissions, add the user (if it’s not already there) and give it full control permissions.

Comment: Mr. Rip sorry frankly to say i not understand