# Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {xxx-xxx} failed due to the following error: 80040154

Tags: .net, com

I develop .Net Com Class Library on 32-bit Windows XP and when port it to 64-bit Windows-Server 2008 client code

```
 var t = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("ProgID");
 var a = Activator.CreateInstance(t);
```

failed with error mentioned in my question subject 
There was similar discussion [Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {XXXX} failed due to the following error: 80040154](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1036856/retrieving-the-com-class-factory-for-component-with-clsid-xxxx-failed-due-to-th)

I double checked the `platform target` (Project Properties / Build / Platform Target) I build my com .net assembly for -- it's **x86**

But the problem still present on 64-bit Win2008 Server...

What shall I check?

Comment: The error is "Class not registered" which indicates the ProgID you're asking for does not exist on the machine. What is the ProgID? Is the software which provides that component installed? If it is an in-process object (i.e. in a DLL not an EXE), is the 32-bit version of it installed? (If not, try setting your build target to x64 to see if you can pick up the 64-bit DLL.)

Comment: Sorry, @Leo, the error is not "Class not registered", it's "Retrieving com class factory failed". I can observe my progId and CLSID in "Wow6432Node" registry section on Windows2008 server.

Comment: 80040154 definitely means "class not registered" ( http://leo.kelbv.com/wc134_errlook.png ). It's possible something is returning that error value incorrectly (or when a more specific value doesn't exist), or that it's some *other* class that was needed somewhere but wasn't registered.

Comment: Where does the code you've given from your question reside?  Is that code, which is calling the COM class, _also_ set for platform target x86?