# exception while executing a program a c# program

Tags: .net, visual-studio, com-interop

i have a program which is .net.when i execute the program am getting this exception .the program is supposed to communicate with fiscal printer.

> Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID
>   {741F1E1B-0D59-4F59-A775-3E1B13721638} failed due to the following
>   error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using FiscPrinter = FiscPrnSys.IFiscPrnIface;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
public class Class1
{
    public List<String> salesITems = new List<String>();
    public String user;
    public String shop;
    public double total;
    public double subtotal;
    public String tax;
    public short data = (short) 8;
    public short parity = (short)0;
    public short stopbit = (short)1;

    public void PrintBon()
    {
        FiscPrnSys.IFiscPrnIface FiscPrinter = new FiscPrnSys.FiscPrnIface();     (this     where the program is bringing this exemption)
        FiscPrinter.Connect("COM2", 9600, data, parity, stopbit);
        FiscPrinter.TestPrinter((short)48, "1,0,1", "HELLO");
        FiscPrinter.Sale("TEST ITEM 1", "A", 2, 2, 0);
        FiscPrinter.Sale("TEST ITEM 1", "A", 2, 2, 0);
        FiscPrinter.Sale("TEST STOCK ITEMS ZERO VAT", "B", 2, 2, 0);
        FiscPrinter.Sale("Cooking Fat Always Ultra", "B", 2, 2, 0);
        FiscPrinter.PrintFiscalText("TEST STOCK ITEMS VATABLE"); 
        FiscPrinter.Sale("001000124", "A", 2, 2, 0);
        FiscPrinter.PrintFiscalText("Kimbo 1 Kg");
        FiscPrinter.Sale("598699484", "A", 5, 5, 0);
        FiscPrinter.PrintFiscalText("Tily Cooking Fat");
        FiscPrinter.Sale("484949404", "A", 2, 2, 0);
        FiscPrinter.Sale("Always ULtra", "A", 10, 2, 0);
        FiscPrinter.Disconnect();
    }
    public void setUser(String user)
    {
        this.user = user;
    }
    public void setShop(String shop)
    {
        this.shop = shop;
    }
    public void addSaleItem(String item)
    {
        salesITems.Add(item);
    }
    public void setDouble(double pTotal)
    {
        this.total = pTotal;
    }
    public void setSubTotal(double sTotal)
    {
        this.subtotal = sTotal;
    }
    public void setTax(String pTax)
    {
        this.tax = pTax;
    }
 }
```

this class is called by another class which is

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Text;
 using IncortexLibrary;

 class Program
 {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Class1 printer = new Class1();
        printer.PrintBon();
    }
 }
```

Output:

```
 Unhandled Exception: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Retrieving the
 COM class factory for component with CLSID {741F1E1B-0D59-4F59-A775-3E1B1372163
8} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception f
rom HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).
 at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOn
 ly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Bo
  olean& bNeedSecurityCheck)
  at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipChec
  kThis, Boolean fillCache)
  at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean s
 kipVisibilityChecks, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache)
  at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)
  at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type)
 at IncortexLibrary.Class1.PrintBon() in C:\Documents and Settings\woodley-who
 lesalers\My Documents\bst project\Projects\IncortexLibrary\IncortexLibrary\Class
 1.cs:line 29
    at ConsoleApp.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Documents and Settings\woodle
 y-wholesalers\My Documents\bst project\Projects\ConsoleApp\ConsoleApp\Program.cs
 :line 15
```

this have given headache.i have registered the files .dll files in system32 but     still it is giving me problems.does it mean i am intiallizing the program in the wrong w ay.the printer is showing to be null.please help because i have tried to walk through the web but am not getting solution

Comment: I believe all exceptions occur during execution. :P

Comment: Exact duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/q/1036856/55209

Comment: @the_ajp yes it is occuring during execution.do you have an idea why is it behaving this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this usually due to permission issues set full control in registry

http://support.software602.com/kb/view.aspx?articleID=987

Comment: "Server Error in '/'" Application. Link is offline