# Reference Microsoft.Office.interop.access.dao.dll cause error C#

Tags: c#, ms-access, dao

I have an application which connect to access 2003.
I'm facing a problem with insert bulk of rows to access, so i came to an solution by using DAO (Microsoft.Office.interop.access.dao.dll) to improve performance of this process as follow this link
[Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {XXXX} failed due to the following error: 80040154](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1036856/retrieving-the-com-class-factory-for-component-with-clsid-xxxx-failed-due-to-t)

But when i open the connect to access by using

> using DAO =Microsoft.Office.interop.access.dao.dll;
> ....
>
> new DAO.DBEngine();

this line gave me an error:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80040154): Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {CD7791B9-43FD-42C5-AE42-8DD2811F0419} failed due to the following error: 80040154

My application is 32 bit and i running the program in a machine with Win xp 32 bit too, It work fine until i start using DAO

I have try many thing that i came up when google, but nothing help, like this:
[Error in create access database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12138901/error-in-create-access-database)

--
More info:
After install

> AccessDatabaseEngine.exe
> **the problem go away**, so i think it must be something like the dll can't register, and then after install the package, somehow it's registered DAO dll.

But i can't not install anything in production server, **so i need a way to manual register the dll**, or something like that, to let the application work without install **AccessDatabaseEngine.exe** package

Please give me any advice

Answer (score 0):

**WORKAROUND:**

The possible workaround is modify your project's platform from 'Any CPU' to 'X86' (in Project's Properties, Build/Platform's Target)

**ROOTCAUSE**

The VSS Interop is a managed assembly using 32-bit Framework and the dll contains a 32-bit COM object. If you run this COM dll in 64 bit environment, you will get the error message.

Comment: didn't... read... the question? - stated that the application is 32-bit (x86), that installing the Access Database Engine would by all accounts fix the issue, but installation is not an option