# Powershell Unset Access .mdb Password - Password Known

Tags: powershell, ms-access-2016

There's an .mdb located on a shared drive in my organization that's password protected and needs to stay password protected. I have the password. I use a local copy for data analysis. The shared drive is very slow for me so I copy it daily using powershell. I need to remove the password manually because the analysis software available to me doesn't support .mdb passwords.

The code below successfully opens the .mdb so I can manually unset the password, but I'd like to automate unsetting the password.

```
$path = "C:\path\to\db\"
$file = "db.mdb"  
$access = New-Object -com Access.Application
$access.Visible = $True
$access.OpenCurrentDataBase($path + $file, $True, "password")
```

I think my problem is I don't understand PowerShell's implementation of the object model. I want to use Database.NewPassword to change the password. In VB implementations it requires a database object, however, and when I substitute `$db = $access.OpenCurrentDataBase($path + $file, $True, "password")` for `$access.OpenCurrentDataBase($path + $file, $True, "password")` the `$db` variable is `$null`.

Is there a way to refer to the database object in PowerShell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manage the database password with Access DDL.

```sql
ALTER DATABASE PASSWORD newpassword oldpassword
```

This is how I removed the password with PowerShell:

```
$path = "C:\Temp\DbPwd_foo.mdb"
$newpassword = "Null"
$oldpassword = "foo"
$accessApp = new-object -com access.application
$accessApp.OpenCurrentDatabase($path, -1, $oldpassword)
$sql = "ALTER DATABASE PASSWORD " + $newpassword + " " + $oldpassword
$accessApp.CurrentProject.Connection.Execute($sql)
$accessApp.Quit()
```

You can restore the previous password by swapping the values of `$newpassword` and `$oldpassword`, and calling `OpenCurrentDatabase` without its password argument.

Answer (score 0):

You can use DAO for that, the [`DbEngine.Compact`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/dbengine-compactdatabase-method-dao) method. It's a pain that powershell does not allow naming parameters and skipping the optionals, though, unless you want to do [complicated stuff](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5575966/7296893).

```
$path = "C:\path\to\db\"
$file = "db.mdb"
$newfile = "decrypted.mdb"
$dbe= New-Object -com DAO.DbEngine.120
$dbe.Compact($path + $file, $path + $newfile, ";LANGID=0x0409;CP=1252;COUNTRY=0", 64, ";PWD=password")
```

Comment: Thank you! When I try to create the object I get the following error: New-Object : Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000} failed
due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).
At line:1 char:8
+ $dbe = New-Object -com DAO.DbEngine
+        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [New-Object], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoCOMClassIdentified,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand

Comment: Should have searched before responding. Looks like it's a 32bit driver in 64bit env problem. My root issue, actually. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12138901/error-in-create-access-database/12139165. Any ideas how to work around it?

Comment: @PKB Try the edit. The database engine is always available if Access is. Usually, requesting the general object gets the version-specific one

Comment: Shouldn't be a 32-bit 64-bit issue if you can use the Access application object. You can always do `$access = New-Object -com Access.Application` and `$dbe = $access.DbEngine`

Comment: Thanks for the ongoing help. `$dbe= New-Object -com DAO.DbEngine.120` gave the same error and `$dbe = $access.DbEngine` returned a null object.

Comment: You ran `$access = New-Object -com Access.Application` before `$dbe = $access.DbEngine`, right? The Access application must have a dbengine property, so that's very odd, if it's missing the only thing I can think of is "do a reinstall"

Comment: I did, indeed. Just checked again for my sanity, but yes. Makes no sense, right?