# Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {88D969C1-F192-11D4-A65F-0040963251E5} failed due to the following error: 80040154

Tags: asp.net, web, 32bit-64bit

I am using visual studio 2010 Express. I have created a website in asp.net.It works in XP but not in Windows 7 premium(64-bit)
I am facing the same problem mentioned [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1036856/retrieving-the-com-class-factory-for-component-with-clsid-xxxx-failed-due-to-t)
I tried to register the DLL using regsvr32 but shows an error as

```
The Module "c:\MyProject\bin\MyDll.dll" was loaded but the entry-point 
DllRegisterServer was not found.
Make sure that "c:\MyProject\bin\MyDll.dll" is a valid DLL or OCX and 
then try again.
```

Also i didnt find any options under properties to set **platform target** or **Target CPU** so that i can convert my website to run for 32bit platform.
I am new to ASP.NET, Please help...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First notion would be that your app is running under a 64-bit application pool in IIS that does not have 32-bit apps enabled, and in that case 32-bit DLLs cannot be loaded into a 64-bit process space. Check that the application pool hosting your site allows 32-bit applications.

VS 2010 Express should be creating 32-bit executables by default; although I have not personally used it, I believe I have read that to build 64-bit executables in the 2010 Express versions you must download an additional SDK, so you're likely building a 32-bit target, thus causing the problem described.

Comment: thank you very much...there was a problem with application pool. I enabled it for 32-bit application using 1> In IIS Manager, select Application Pools. 2>In the list of Application Pools, select the application pool you have configured. 3> In the Actions pane, select Advanced Settings under Edit Application Pool.4> Expand the General settings, set Enable 32-bit Applications to True, and click OK.

Comment: Great! Glad I was able to help.

Answer (score 1):

I got this dialog trying to run the Visio x32 FlowChartSampleVBNET add-in. The dialog appeared with CLSID{00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} which pointed to Excel. I had Excel x64 installed on my x64 machine. Apparently, the mismatch between Visio x32 and Excel x64 was causing the problem. After uninstalling Microsoft Office 2013 x64 and reinstalling Microsoft Office 2013 x32, I could run the add-in without error.

Answer (score 0):

Enabling 32-bit application in IIS did not worked in my case!

When I have **installed crystal report for visual studio and crystal report runtime engine (64-bit) worked** in my case!

Some other suggests that, this problem could be resolved by **installing both 32-bit and 64-bit runtime engine**!

You can find similar issue here [Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {XXXX} failed due to the following error: 80040154](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1036856/retrieving-the-com-class-factory-for-component-with-clsid-xxxx-failed-due-to-t/72420920#72420920)

[image]