# Deploying website using a COM interface to IIS causes class not registered error

Tags: asp.net, windows-7, iis-7, com, 32bit-64bit

I have an ASP.NET site that needs to use a COM interface that we developed. When I test the website within the visual studio environment, it works fine. However, when I go to deploy the site to IIS, I receive an error stating

`Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {0716BE95-6372-46B2-B42D-9FC0ED5E0FE3} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered`

I've tried a few things

1. Ensuring that the dll containing the class IS in fact registered. I made sure that the entry in the registry matched the CLSID that the error stated it failed to load.
2. Unregistering the dll and re-registering it using regsvr32.exe
3. Following the advice in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15563083/connecting-to-a-com-interface-in-an-aspx-code-behind-running-on-iis). The class I'm trying to use is not a service though, so I'm not sure how relevant that question is to my issue.
4. Following the advice in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14019401/80070005-access-is-denied-when-asp-net-website-with-crystal-report-is-deployed-o?lq=1). Again, I'm not sure how relevant that is since that question states that it is an access denied error.
5. Restarting my machine after unregistering and re-registering the dll
6. Changing the Platform target of my project from `Any CPU` to `x86` as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2892577/1224272). This causes another problem. `Could not load file or assembly 'TestWebSimpleMath' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.` which I think is a step backwards.

I'm running Windows 7 Ultimate edition 64 bit.

Any help would be great. I've been trying to get this working for nearly 9 hours with no luck.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Reason**:
Your service was built against 'Any CPU' causing you errors on 64bit where you are using COM components. You need to build it for 'x86'.

**Solution**:
In Visual Studio, right click on the **PROJECT** then select **PROPERTIES**. Click the **BUILD** tab then under **PLATFORM TARGET** change **Any CPU** to **X86**.

*Possible duplicate of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1036856/retrieving-the-com-class-factory-for-component-with-clsid-xxxx-failed-due-to-t).*
**Update**:Enable 32 bit application
 Go to IIS -> Application Pool -> Advance Settings -> Enable 32-bit Applications
*check this related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41449/i-get-a-an-attempt-was-made-to-load-a-program-with-an-incorrect-format-error-o)*

Comment: As I stated in my question I've already tried that which resulted in the error `Could not load file or assembly 'TestWebSimpleMath' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.`

Comment: Ok, now I'm getting the access denied error, which is closer :D I'll follow the advice in this question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14019401/80070005-access-is-denied-when-asp-net-website-with-crystal-report-is-deployed-o?lq=1) and hopefully that will fix everything up. Thanks for your help. I'll let you know how it goes

Comment: It's always those damned little checkboxes. It worked after I made the app pool run as a user that has permissions to access the COM interfaces. Thanks. I owe you.

Comment: I can't tell you how often we run into this in production systems. The setting on the app pool is always the culprit.