# server error in '/Services_DEV' application

Tags: asp.net, iis-7.5, windows-server-2008-r2

I was getting the below error as I was unable to find the correct solution...Actually I  found some solutions, and I tried them but none in the solutions helped me to resolve the below error.

### Server Error in '/Services_DEV' Application.

```
Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {9F8D4F16-0F61-4A38-98B3-1F6F80F11C87} failed due to the following error: 80070005 Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)). 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {9F8D4F16-0F61-4A38-98B3-1F6F80F11C87} failed due to the following error: 80070005 Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)). 

ASP.NET is not authorized to access the requested resource. Consider granting access rights to the resource to the ASP.NET request identity. ASP.NET has a base process identity (typically {MACHINE}\ASPNET on IIS 5 or Network Service on IIS 6 and IIS 7, and the configured application pool identity on IIS 7.5) that is used if the application is not impersonating. If the application is impersonating via <identity impersonate="true"/>, the identity will be the anonymous user (typically IUSR_MACHINENAME) or the authenticated request user. 

To grant ASP.NET access to a file, right-click the file in Explorer, choose "Properties" and select the Security tab. Click "Add" to add the appropriate user or group. Highlight the ASP.NET account, and check the boxes for the desired access.

Source Error: 


[No relevant source lines]


Source File: c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\rhenusservices_dev\19c0008c\aab4c325\App_Web_default.aspx.cdcab7d2.csyixg6l.0.cs    Line: 0 

Stack Trace: 


[UnauthorizedAccessException: Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {9F8D4F16-0F61-4A38-98B3-1F6F80F11C87} failed due to the following error: 80070005 Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)).]
   _Default..ctor() +141
   ASP.default_aspx..ctor() in c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\rhenusservices_dev\19c0008c\aab4c325\App_Web_default.aspx.cdcab7d2.csyixg6l.0.cs:0
   __ASP.FastObjectFactory_app_web_default_aspx_cdcab7d2_csyixg6l.Create_ASP_default_aspx() in c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\rhenusservices_dev\19c0008c\aab4c325\App_Web_default.aspx.cdcab7d2.csyixg6l.1.cs:0
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildResultCompiledType.CreateInstance() +32
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath(VirtualPath virtualPath, Type requiredBaseType, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp) +109
   System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory.GetHandlerHelper(HttpContext context, String requestType, VirtualPath virtualPath, String physicalPath) +31
   System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory.System.Web.IHttpHandlerFactory2.GetHandler(HttpContext context, String requestType, VirtualPath virtualPath, String physicalPath) +40
   System.Web.HttpApplication.MapHttpHandler(HttpContext context, String requestType, VirtualPath path, String pathTranslated, Boolean useAppConfig) +167
   System.Web.MapHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +128
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +184




--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.1016
```

Comment: Can you give more information. what do you do to get this error? is it on server or loacl?

Comment: I was getting this error in server system...as i deployed my application in server system and testing the application so i was getting this error

Comment: it says 80070005 Access is denied. so probably see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14019401/80070005-access-is-denied-when-asp-net-website-with-crystal-report-is-deployed-o

Comment: specially if your server is 64bit then for application pool enable 32-bit

Comment: i already set apppoolIdentity 32-bit to true and tried but that does't helped me....

Comment: try this too http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/Logon/code/code_80070005.htm