# Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

I get a **80070005 Access is denied** error when attempting to deploy a Crystal Report to the server. I have tried every solution in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14019401/80070005-access-is-denied-when-asp-net-website-with-crystal-report-is-deployed-o) but nothing seems to work. How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```
1.)Goto inetmgr or IIS
2.)Application pools
3.).NET Framework Version.
```