# How to use 3rd party library with WCF service?

Tags: wcf

I have the task to "exlude" 3rd party 32bit library from our app so we can build it as 64bit.
For that we decide use WCF service that will work with this dll and our app will call this service.
The WCF service runs but when I try invoke the methid on this service it gives me error -

```
Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {...} failed due to the following error: 0040154 Class not registered.
```

The dll is registred, reference to it (in WCF project) I added from COM tab.
What I can do with this?

Just added - endpoints configured as net.pipe because service (self-hosted) and client will run on one machine.

Comment: Take a look at this question - there are a couple things you can try:  http://stackoverflow.com/q/1036856/745969

Comment: I've already did try all from that topic.

Comment: 1. When I build my WCF in x86 I can't run it from VS to debug (error: WcfSvcHost encountered a critical error). 2. The workaround registry doesn't work for Windows 7. 3.Add dll to Component Service --> COM+ Application kind of works :( but ... First - another apps that use this dll stoped work. Second - the one method (connection) works but another method (getRequest) return error (no database connection) and finally when I change Activation type from Server App to Library - my WCF get same error (about regestration) but other applications are working.