# .Net Web service using HIS adapter is throwing error in VS2010

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, biztalk, clsid

I have a web service that uses HIS adapter. It was developed in 3.5 .Net Framework and work smoothly in Window XP.

Now I am trying to run the same web service in Window 7 using VS2008. following error is thrown.

Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {39D53E15-A96D-11D2-A035-0000F663518E} failed due to the following error: 80040154.

Please help me to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this old problem, try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1036856/retrieving-the-com-class-factory-for-component-with-clsid-xxxx-failed-due-to-t).

> In VS - project properties - in the Build tab - platform target =X86