# Troubles Migrating VB script (reliant on vendor API) from 32-bit Windows Server 2008 to a 64-bit Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: vb.net, windows, visual-studio-2010, dll

I'm trying to migrate an script written in Visual Basic from **32-bit Windows Server 2008** to a **64-bit Windows Server 2012 R2**.  The script connects to SQL Servers, performs some queries and executes calls to a vendor/third-party API.

The dll file with the vendor's API code was not included in the new server installation, so I copied it from the old server.  In order for me to be able to add the dll (via `Add Reference` option) to the project, I had to run the dll through [`Tlbimp.exe`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tt0cf3sx(v=vs.110).aspx).

When I try to run the executable for my script on the new Windows server, I get the infamous error:

> Unhandled Exception: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException:
>   Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {...} failed
>   due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception
>   from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).

I assume this is a complaint about the third party dll not being registered, so I have tried...

**...setting the platform to x86**

As per:
    [Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {XXXX} failed due to the following error: 80040154](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1036856/retrieving-the-com-class-factory-for-component-with-clsid-xxxx-failed-due-to-t).  In the MS Visual Basic 2010 Express IDE, I have set the platform to `Active (x86)` which is the only option I have.

**...placing the dll in the System32 folder**

**...registering the dll**

Using [`regsvr32.exe`](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/249873).  But I gett he error:

> The module "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\vendor.dll" was loaded but the
>   entry-point DllRegisterServer was not found...

Admittedly, I don't know the basics when it comes to programming for Windows and I feel like I may be missing something simple or fundamental here.

How do I get my VB application to run on the new server with the vendor API (dll)?

Comment: Clearly you need to register the COM server. I suggest you follow the documentation, and if you get stuck, talk to the vendor.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no documentation nor support from the vendor :(

Comment: Well, I guess you'll need to keep trying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was indeed a silly error on my part...

When attempting to register the dll, I tried to register the dll that was converted by `Tlbimp.exe` (the one that I could add as a reference to the project), instead of the original dll file that I copied from the old server.

The original dll file registers successfully and the executable can now run.