# How to deploy the web application

Tags: asp.net, windows, dll, deployment, 32bit-64bit

I want to deploy the web application in 2008 server

In web application am using one 3rd party dll file for encryption (dencrpt.dll)

Deployed the application in windows2008 server, during runtime 3rd tool showing error for registration as

```
"Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {XXXX} failed due to the following error: 80040154"
```

Then i registered the dll file but dll file is not working at all during the runtime.

I done the following exercise to sort out the issues but no result

```
1) Builded the application in 32bit environment (x86 mode) in windows7 operation system and deployed in windows 2008 server
2) Registerd the 3rd party dll file from the deployed bin folder using regsvr32 in server 2008 (selected cmd as Administration mode for registration)
3) Enabled 32bit enivormnent in application pool in server2008
4) Copied the 3rd party dll file to system32 & syswow64 and registerd using regsvr32 in server2008, registered succeed. (selected cmd as Administration mode for registration)
```

During runtime Application not using the dencrypt.dll and also not showing any error during the runtime, so it is skipping. application need to use the dll file.

Note: This is not a duplication question i also followed the same instruction from this link (`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1036856/retrieving-the-com-class-factory-for-component-with-clsid-xxxx-failed-due-to-t`) but still facing the issue

And also there is not other dll dependency

Please any one help me to sort out this issue.