# Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {abcdef} failed due to the following error: 80040154

Tags: com, server, windows-server-2008-r2, terminal-server

I am getting following error when trying to run an application on a Windows Server 2008 on Terminal Server:

> Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {abcdef} failed due to the following error: 80040154

I connect via remote to the Terminal Server and to the Terminal Server one requiered .dll is "passed".

I tried several things, like compiling one version of the application in x86, trying to register the interop dll etc. but nothing works.
In the end I tried one Version which works on a customers Server but the same problem.
At client site, there are entries in the registry under

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID{3E7F07BE-37A9-4F37-894E-6316543BBE71}
>
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\xxCOM.xx\CLSID

xx is the name of the applicaction
at server side there is no entry.
Maybe it is just an wrong or missing configuration on terminal server?
Both, client and server are running on virtual machines.
Any suggestions?

Thank you!

Some links i followed:
[same error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1036856/retrieving-the-com-class-factory-for-component-with-clsid-xxxx-failed-due-to-t) 
[DCOMCNFG](http://technoblogy.net/retrieving-the-com-class-factory-for-component-with-clsid-00024500-0000-0000-c000-000000000046-failed-due-to-the-following-error-80040154/)

Comment: The *.dll on Client side is 32 bit i fotgott to mention.

Comment: Ok, my problem is solved.
It was an intern problem that the application wanted the com object but the installer was giving the activex object.. 
now it works :)