# Compiling a VB6 COM DLL through command line gets a different CLSID each time

Tags: com, vb6, clsid

Let `dllproject.vbp` be a DLL VB6 project.

Each time i compile through this Line :

```
VB6.EXE /MAKE dllproject.vbp  /outdir somedir
```

The compiler produce a dll with another CLSID. Why ?

(EDIT)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Found why here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1547658.aspx?INTEROP%20CLSID%20changes%20every%20new%20build%20How%20can%20I%20solve%20it%20as%20application%20asp%20net%20does%20not%20stop%20when%20new%20DLL%20is%20registred%20).

In a few word, binary compatibility must be activated. A good way is to keep a copy of the dll (renamed .cmp) for example and reference this copy for version compatibility (Project -> [project name] properties....

Comment: You'll want to read [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa242136(v=vs.60).aspx) as well, if you are making any changes to the component.

Comment: Thanks. In fact I had issue with binary compatibility (forgot why), and disabled it. Since I compiled before interactively, I didn't noticed such change, cause DLL compilation and releasing was done manually... Now it's scripted, so the problem became more apparent.